# Use different language level for test and production

Tags: java, intellij-idea

We have a project that builds a library (a jar file) with Java 6 compatibility, but our unit tests are run using Java 8 and they use Java 8 syntax. Our Maven pom.xml file includes this:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
            <testSource>1.8</testSource>
            <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The IntelliJ IDEA project is built as a Maven project. Unfortunately, IntelliJ IDEA treats the whole project as using jdk 1.6, even the unit tests, so the editor window puts a red line under Java 8 syntax (such as lambda expressions) saying this is not supported in Java 6. Is there a way to tell it to use Java 8 syntax for the tests and Java 6 for production code? They live in separate directory trees but are part of the same module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the IntelliJ IDEA documentation, one can configure different JDLs for different modules, but they don't support different JDK for test and source code.

There's even an official response:

> It's not supported at the moment:
>   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85478.

(More details here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001335500-Set-different-java-language-level-between-source-code-and-test-in-the-lastest-stable-version-of-Idea-)

There's a somewhat clumsy workaround - you can use different Maven profile which will be used only for IDEA:

```xml
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>ide</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      <property>
        <name>idea.maven.embedder.version</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <testSource>1.8</testSource>
            <testTarget>1.8</testTarget>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
  </profile>
<profiles>
```

More detailed information can be found here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85478